# Choose another partition for /home directory during installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, home-directory, partitioning

Since this question as addition in another question i created got lost, here is it as a separate question.

Is there a possibility to choose another partition for /home directory during installation of Ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is, you need to select the advanced partition option:

[image]

Once you see this screen you need to resize the root partition (ext4) and then use the Add button to add a new partition:

[image]

Where you see "mount point" that should say `/home` and the size should be an acceptably large size for your home partition.

WARNING! Having a separate partition has it's down sides, you will not be able to adjust the amount of free space between your ubuntu partition and your home directory later, it's very fixed so think carefully about how much space you really need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, during the install you will need to choose custom partitioning and manually defined the partition structure. Make sure you set the mount point for your home partition to /home .