# I am interested in dual booting window's 7 32-bit and ubuntu 12.04. How to do partitions?

Tags: partitioning

i intend to use half harddisk to win7 and other to ubuntu

my pc info
500 gb HD [250 for win7 and other for ubuntu]
4 gb ram!
amd phenom II X2 555 processor 3.20Hz! 
i am confused how to do partitions i will install winds 7 first after it ubuntu! needed help!

Thanks in Advance! =)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but following procedure should work:

1. install Windows 7
2. defrag internal hdd
3. reboot into Ubuntu livecd (cd or usb) - set the boot sequence to cd or usb before hdd in your bios
4. select Ubuntu install
5. select dual-boot with Windows 7
6. drag the hdd size bar to the middle (left region is for Windows 7 and right region is for Ubuntu)
7. if connected to the internet, select update and install proprietary check-boxes
8. proceed with installation which will update the MBR
9. reboot - default grub boot selection is Ubuntu (top) and Windows 7 will be displayed last (bottom)
10. when logged into Ubuntu, bring up a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and run

    `sudo apt-get update

     sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

     sudo apt-get install -f`

Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution:**

Leave half the disk unpartitioned and unused, during Windows install. Ubuntu install process will find the empty space and create its own sets of partitions. Ubuntu uses ext4 formats for partitions. Creating partitions using Windows, for Ubuntu will not work.

**Advanced Solution:**

Keep unallocated space for future use during Windows installation as before.

During Ubuntu installation, choose the "Something Else" when it comes to the type of installation so that you can create your own sets of Ubuntu partition.

I recommend 3 partitions, `/` (also known as root), `/home`, and Swap. The size of the first two will depend on your usage needs.

For normal desktop uses 30GB `/` should be sufficient for updates and new software you may want to install. If you want to run web server type of things, you may need more.

For normal desktop use, `/home' takes most of the space. This is where all the users' data files like music, photos, videos, etc. will stay.

Swap can be small, say 2-4GB, unless you want to hibernate your PC, in that case, 6GB.

The `/` and `/home` should be formatted ext4. Swap has its own format in the drop down list.

For more on `/home` see [Home on a different partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29689/home-on-a-different-partition)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have 250GB free space as you mentioned. When you began the installation of ubuntu, it will ask for a partitioning method. The easy way is to select `"use free space"` option. well, if you want to set up the partitioning manually, select `"Something else"` option. then create two partitions as follows. Partition 1 : `Size 4096 mb, filesystem type : swap`Partition 2 : `Size : fill it to maximum allowable size, filesystem type : ext4, mount point : / and check the format option also.`