# dual booting windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 with home on different drive

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, inspiron

I have laptop with a 256 gb SSD with windows already installed and i want to install ubuntu on the same drive.BUT with the "/home" partition on a second 1tb HDD(600gb for windows and 400 gb for ubuntu). is it possible? will it cause problems down the line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Home on a different partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29689/home-on-a-different-partition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possibile. When you install ubuntu choose 'Manual partitioning':
- Create a new partition in your SSD and select as mountpoint '/'
- Create a new partition in your HD and select as mountpoint '/home'

If you want further information about partioning and mountpoints: [help - Partitioning issue](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning%20issues?action=show&redirect=Partitioning#Why_use_multiple_partitions.3F) or [Partitioning/Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home).

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common installation type. Just choose manual disk partitioning, when install. Create / partition on your SSD and /home on you HDD. Do not forget to set mount points correctly.