# why i have unity 5.20.0 installed, if they are already making unity 8?

Tags: 12.04, updates

I thought i have the lastest version available, i updated very resently. It's the lastest version in repository.

Also, emacs 24 somehow not in repository either, only version 23.

Update:

my ubuntu version is Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Comment: First: Which Ubuntu Version are you using? Check this by typing `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that's right: [→ look!](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity).

Ubuntu 13.04 is coming up with Unity 7 [→ Additional information (German)](http://www.linux-magazin.de/NEWS/Ubuntu-13.04-mit-Unity-7-weniger-Support-und-ohne-Wubi)

Why is it important for you to get a higher version of Unity? E. g. you could upgrade Ubuntu to Ubuntu 13.04…

Comment: i see, thanks. So, how to upgrade to 13.04, without downloading livecd and reinstalling everything? Update manager doesn't show anything. I want to update just to check if they are fixed one bug in the new version.

Comment: I just used [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) to find out: (http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-04-from-12-10-in-ubuntu-via-software-updater/)

Comment: what was your search query?

Comment: Oh, I forgot, but `ubuntu upgrade` seems to show good results, too…

Comment: it gives me http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade . I hope there is a easy way to downgrade... Maybe i should just install it separately...

Comment: Why do you need the higher version of unity? **If** this is really important, I would copy all the files onto an external drive, and would install 13.04. Further I would always recommend you to use a → [separate home](http://askubuntu.com/a/17575/94570) partition.